# RequestMapping isn't reaching in the controller and thus list isn't showing on the JSP page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller, request-mapping

I'm developing a simple application of tender management in which I'm using J2EE, Spring-mvc and CRUD operations on Eclipse IDE
I've to retrieve the list of tenders from the database and show in the JSP using controller. The JSP page is mapped in the `@RequestMapping` but the mapping isn't executing and hence the code following it isn't reaching.

I've tried non- crud operations before and have used different methods including ModelAndView and String but the issue is with mapping which isn't able to run when loading the required JSP. No error is being shown.

Here is the mapping call in the Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/viewTendersByUser")
public String viewTender(Model m) {
    System.out.println("in edit tender user controller");
    List<tender> tender = userDao.getTenderByCreator(name);
    m.addAttribute("tender", tender);
    System.out.println("in ctender after view tender");
    System.out.println(""+tender);
    return "viewTendersByUser";
}
```

This is the method in DAO which I'm calling but isn't actually reached

```
@Override
public List<tender> getTenderByCreator(String name) {
    String sql = "select * from tenderdb where publisher = 
              '"+name+"'";
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql,new RowMapper<tender>(){
        public tender mapRow(ResultSet rs, int row) throws SQLException {
            tender t = new tender();
            t.settName(rs.getString(1));
            t.setOpening(rs.getTimestamp(2));
            t.setClosing(rs.getTimestamp(3));
            t.setMinBid(rs.getDouble(4));
            t.settDesc(rs.getString(5));
            return t;
        }
    });
}
```

And this is the JSP I'm trying to show data in:

```
<h3>List of Tenders</h3>
  <table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">  
  <tr><th>Tender Name</th><th>Opening Date</th><th>Closing Date</th><th>Minimum Bid</th><th>Tender Description</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>  

  <c:forEach var="row" items="${tender}">
      <tr>
          <td>${row.tName}</td>
          <td>${row.opening}</td>
          <td>${row.closing}</td>
          <td>${row.minBid}</td>
          <td>${row.tDesc}</td>
          <td><a href="editTender/${tender.id}">Edit</a></td>
          <td><a href="deleteTender/${tender.id}">Delete</a></td>           
      </tr>
  </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Expected results should be the list of tenders from the database onto the `viewTendersByUser.jsp`.
Actual result is the JSP page being loaded but the contents to be received from controller aren't showing which traces to mapping not being called and actually nothing is happening.
Even an error or exception would be easy to debug but there's no output.

Comment: If the JSP is showing, the request mapping is working. One thing is that you are using String concating to create a query **never** do this.

Comment: Query is fine for now but the issue is with RequestMapping in Controller. JSP is loading but the contents it should be showing is not even getting received  in the List object in the request mapping. Moreover, the sysouts are not printing whish says the issue is with mapping. If you can help with that?

Comment: What does this line `System.out.println(""+tender);` print?

Comment: It isn't reaching. Even this    '''System.out.println("in edit tender user controller");'''    isn't printing.

Comment: Then you are directly accessing the JSP instead of using the request mapping.

Comment: are you sure your controllers are getting registered? can you post your mvc configurations?